# Oracle Trigger Error for updating timestamp field before update & insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am creating a trigger on a Table Name ADM I added a field

```
UPD_DATETIME TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Following is my trigger code

```
create or replace trigger TRG_UPD_DATETIME
 before insert or update
  on adm 
 FOR EACH ROW
  declare
begin
:NEW.UPD_DATETIME:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
end TRG_UPD_DATETIME;
```

I am getting following error's when I am trying to compile:

> Error(12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `DECLARE` .. you don't need that in there.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955